# xsl for-each-group, group-by selected child elements and attributes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'm new to XSL, but found it to be quite interesting. I am using it to build XSD's so we can use data binding when interfacing a really old system that lacks a proper schema.

I'm stuck on something that I believe is a quite simple issue, but after several hours of testing and googling (starting to doubt my Google-skills here...) I feel that I need to ask :-)

Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classes>
    <class>
        <name>param1/stateSettings</name>
        <list>
            <options>
                <default>0</default>
                <option key="0" value="Disabled"/>
                <option key="1" value="Enabled"/>
            </options>
        </list>
    </class>
    <class>
        <name>param2/stateSettings</name>
        <list>
            <options>
                <default>0</default>
                <option key="1" value="Enabled"/>
                <option key="0" value="Disabled"/>
            </options>
        </list>
    </class>
    <class>
        <name>param3/stateSettings</name>
        <list>
            <options>
                <default>1</default>
                <option key="1" value="Enabled"/>
                <option key="0" value="Disabled"/>
            </options>
        </list>
    </class>
    <class>
        <name>param4/stateSettings</name>
        <list>
            <options>
                <default>0</default>
                <option key="1" value="Disabled"/>
                <option key="0" value="Enabled"/>
            </options>
        </list>
    </class>
</classes>
```

I would (ultimately) get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:simpleType name="stateSettingsType">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>
            <replaces>param1/stateSettings</replaces>
            <replaces>param2/stateSettings</replaces>
            <replaces>param3/stateSettings</replaces>
            <grouping-key value="0:1:Disabled:Enabled"/>
         </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Enabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
         <xs:enumeration value="0">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Disabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
   <xs:simpleType name="stateSettings2Type">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>
            <replaces>param4/stateSettings</replaces>
            <grouping-key value="1:0:Disabled:Enabled"/>
         </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Disabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
         <xs:enumeration value="0">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Enabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

(The **grouping-key** is just there for reference, the content does not matter)

My XSL so far is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="options">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="option"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="option">
        <xs:enumeration value="{@key}">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <xsl:element name="dataBinding">
                        <xsl:attribute name="enum" select="@value"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:element name="replaces">
            <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="classes">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="class" group-by="substring-after(name, '/')">
            <xsl:variable name="typeName" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/list" group-by="string-join((options/option/@key, options/option/@value), ':')">
                <xsl:variable name="newTypeName">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() gt 1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($typeName,format-number(position(),'#'),'Type'),'')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($typeName,'Type'),'')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xs:simpleType name="{$newTypeName}">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="../name"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:element name="grouping-key">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="options"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="classes"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current XSL output (the XSD) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:simpleType name="stateSettingsType">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>
            <replaces>param1/stateSettings</replaces>
            <grouping-key value="0:1:Disabled:Enabled"/>
         </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="0">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Disabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
         <xs:enumeration value="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Enabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
   <xs:simpleType name="stateSettings2Type">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>
            <replaces>param2/stateSettings</replaces>
            <replaces>param3/stateSettings</replaces>
            <grouping-key value="1:0:Enabled:Disabled"/>
         </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Enabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
         <xs:enumeration value="0">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Disabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
   <xs:simpleType name="stateSettings3Type">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>
            <replaces>param4/stateSettings</replaces>
            <grouping-key value="1:0:Disabled:Enabled"/>
         </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="1">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Disabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
         <xs:enumeration value="0">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <dataBinding enum="Enabled"/>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

So what is my problem? Well, actually there is two things that need to be fixed to get the "ultimate" output, but I would suffice with just solving one.

Problem 1 is related to the grouping done in the for-each-group. I need to group based on *some* of the content of **options**. My current string-based grouping is sensitive to the order of **option** elements. Elements **param1**, **param2** and **param3** is the same and should be refactored down to one simpleType in the XSD. **param4** has the key/value inversed and should be created as a new simpleType (and Yes, the old system actually uses this kind of "schema"... Not confusing at all :-D)
I can't base the grouping on the whole **options** since there is other stuff in there that is irrelevant in this scope and will mess up the grouping.

Problem 2 is more cosmetic. It would be nice if the first simpleType replaces the types that is most common, i.e if I have 58 identical **class** and 2 that is somewhat different I would like the most common simpleType to have the name without a sequence number.

(Note the **default** elements is not relevant for creating types in the XSD, but I will be revisiting them a a later stage in my XSL when creating the xsd elements, which can have default values)

I hope someone is kind enough to tell my what I'm missing. Please let me know of any other problems I might have in my code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you first want to sort the `option` elements, so the following is your code plus a function for sorting and an inserted function call to compute the grouping key with the sorted options:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="mf">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:sort" as="element(option)*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="element(option)*"/>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$input">
            <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(@key)"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="options">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="option"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="option">
        <xs:enumeration value="{@key}">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <xsl:element name="dataBinding">
                        <xsl:attribute name="enum" select="@value"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:element name="replaces">
            <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="classes">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="class" group-by="substring-after(name, '/')">
            <xsl:variable name="typeName" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/list" group-by="string-join(for $opt in mf:sort(options/option) return ($opt/@key, $opt/@value), ':')">
                <xsl:variable name="newTypeName">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() gt 1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($typeName,format-number(position(),'#'),'Type'),'')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($typeName,'Type'),'')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xs:simpleType name="{$newTypeName}">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="../name"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:element name="grouping-key">
                                <xsl:attribute name="value" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="options"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="classes"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 3.0 with XPath 3.1 (as already supported by Saxon 9.7 PE and EE) you can use the XPath `sort` function and the `!` operator to get a more compact expression:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/list" group-by="string-join(sort(options/option, function($opt) { $opt/xs:integer(@key) }) ! (@key, @value), ':')">
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! I was thinking about some sorting but I could'nt find out how to get it done. It's not all that intuitive, this language :-)

Comment: @dahook, XPath 3.1 as already supported in XSLT 3.0 and Saxon 9.7 PE and EE has a `sort` function to sort sequences, so I have added a line showing its use. But higher order functions and inline functions are also something people need to get used to if they don't have some background in functional programming. On the other hand, procedural and object-oriented programming languages like C# or Java have added similar constructs, Javascript has had them for years, so perhaps it is already intuitive.